# How to click on javascript hyperlink element using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

my goal is to use selenium python to click on this hyperlink element , here are the 3 solutions I have tried, none of them worked.

```
<div class="navigation_item">
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="navigationMenu('students');">Students (165)</a>
</div>
```

Solution 1:

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Students (165)').click()
```

> error message: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Students (165)"}

Solution 2:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[7]/a').click()
```

> error message: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[7]/a"}

Solution 3:use javascript code

```
javascript = "document.getElementsByClassName('navigation_item')[3].click();"
driver.execute_script(javascript)
```

> error message:selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

So, what went wrong with each solution? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **Students (165)** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Students (165)"))).click()
  ```
- Using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Students ("))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.navigation_item>a[onclick^='navigationMenu'][onclick*='students']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='navigation_item']/a[starts-with(@onclick, 'navigationMenu') and contains(., 'Students')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score -1):

It probably throws an error because page isn't loaded when you're checking for element. Try using:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.implicitly_wait(5)
```

Then you can use your first solution:
`driver.find_element_by_link_text('Students (165)').click()`

This should be triggered on find element setting timeout for 5 seconds.